# Python spinbox not getting value

Tags: python, tkinter

I looked everywhere on the internet and could not find the answer. When I use sp.get() in the for loop, it does not get the changed value, only the value I set with sp.set() (right after the spinbox is defined).
Here is my code:

```
w = Label(window5, text = "Number of People to serve", font="50")
w.pack()
def tab5():
        window5 = Tk()
        window5.geometry('300x200')
        window5.title("How many people are you surving")
        sp = Spinbox(window5, from_= 1, to = 1000000000000000000)
        sp.set(1)
        sp.pack()
        Submit = Button(window5, text = "submit", command = window7.deiconify)
        Submit.pack()
        window5.deiconify()
        window1.withdraw()
        result1 = tk.Label(window6, text = dFriedChickenMeathod)
        result1.pack()
        window7.geometry('800x800')
        print(sp.get())
        for items in dFriedChickenIngrediants:
                A = dFriedChickenIngrediants[items]
                e = sp.get()
                result2 = Label(window7, text = str(A * int(e) + items))
                result2.pack()
```

Comment: You are calling `sp.get()` just a few milliseconds after creating `sp` - there is absolutely no chance that the user has changed the value yet.  You need to do the last half of this function *later*, when the user has indicated that they've finished making changes - probably via clicking a button.

Answer (score 0):

`Spinbox` has no set method. You need to create a `tkinter.IntVar()` and include it in you `Spinbox` declaration.

```py
var = tk.IntVar(value=1)
sp = tk.Spinbox(window, textvariable = var, from_= 1, to = 1000000000000000000)
sp.pack()
```

Comment: I think OP is using `ttk.Spinbox` which has `set()` function.

Comment: @acw1668 `ttk.Spinbox` has a `setvar` and `getvar` but I don't see any `set` method.

Comment: See [doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/tkinter.ttk.html#tkinter.ttk.Spinbox.set).

Comment: Yep my bad. imported tkinter as ttk, oops.